# What is use of sanitize attribute in html type field in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, language-translation

In html type of field one attribute is available, In which we can pass **True/False**.

```
body_html = fields.Html('Body', translate=True, sanitize=False, help="Rich-text/HTML version of the message (placeholders may be used here)")

body_html = fields.Html('Body', translate=True, sanitize=True, help="Rich-text/HTML version of the message (placeholders may be used here)")
```

**If we set True/False then we are getting same result.**

What is difference if we set True/False in this field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just telling Odoo if to clean html code, like deleting scripts, tags/nodes, etc. For more information look into [the code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/df135166799ccafd49c2aa684bb0ff845af31b09/odoo/tools/mail.py#L158).